# blender move vertices on X-Y Plane

Tags: blender

Is there a way to constrain movement of vertices to a plane?

You can constrain it along an axis by pressing "x", "y", or "z".  I want the z ordinate to remain stable while I move in the other two axis. I can always do a bit of "x" and a bit of "y", and more "x", and more "y", ...  but as a newbie will forget and get myself messed up.

What I am trying to do is create a two-d shape on the x-y plane, that I will then use the solidify option to make 3D.  For my work having "z" set to 0 is perfect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 5):

Press `g` once then `shift` and `z` together to move along only x-y plane. Go into front orthographic view to verify object is only moving along x and y axis or look at the Z location.

Comment: As a complete noob; you have saved me HOURS! Thanks :)